# Ubuntu 20.04 on DualBoot fail 90% of tries - Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, initramfs

I just installed Ubuntun 20.04 on a Dell Latitude 7400 on DualBoot.

I had to remove the RST as mentioned on this post : https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347

It works but now I need to test 5 or more times to boot.
After the grub screen, most of the time i have a black screen.
Sometimes I have this error :
`Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed`

And then it starts.

---

here is a file called `initramfs.conf`

**cat /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf**

```
MODULES=most

BUSYBOX=auto

COMPCACHE_SIZE=""

COMPRESS=lz4


DEVICE=

NFSROOT=auto RUNSIZE=10%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems to be a widespread problem. you might look into this post:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1835660

Somebody there suggests to change lz4 to gzip (comment #73) in the file mentioned by you

/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs

Pls update because I have the same problem